# Find childrens folder with find_files php function

Tags: php

Need the function to find the folders 173 and 508 within children off children path.
Was trying to use:

```
find_files( $pathfolder .'/*'. '/*' . '173/', '.jpg$', 'move_orders');
```

The main code:

```
$pathfolder = "/home/production/ready/ordrers/";

find_files( $pathfolder . '173/', '/.jpg$/', 'move_orders');
find_files( $pathfolder . '508/', '/.jpg$/', 'move_orders');

function find_files($path, $pattern, $callback) {
    $path = rtrim(str_replace("\\", "/", $path), '/') . '/'  ;
    $matches = Array();
    $entries = Array();
    $dir = dir($path);
    while (false !== ($entry = $dir->read())) {
    $entries[] = $entry;
    }
    $dir->close();
```

Comment: Van you post your folder structure and desired output?

Comment: You can not feed a path with wildcards to `dir`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you need to get all the pictures in exact subfolder. You can use [`glob()`](https://www.php.net/glob):

```php
function find_files($path, $folder, $extension) {
    return glob("$path/$folder/*.$extension");
}

$pathfolder = "/home/production/ready/ordrers/";

find_files( $pathfolder, '173', 'jpg');
find_files( $pathfolder, '508', 'jpg');
```

You also have `$calback`, but I don't see any usage of it.